# Java read from file and put to map

Tags: java

Hello i have lots of files txt in some folder, Each file txt has that same structure:

```
Name Surname
Date of Birth
titles works of authors
```

like:

```
Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart

1756 w Salzburgu

Requiem d-moll 

ave verum corpus

lacrymosa
piano sonata no. 16
etc.
```

and i would like create HashMap:

- Key is author
- Values are works

in my program i dont need name of birth but i cant delete this line from txt.

so far i wrote that code:

```
  public void check() throws IOException {

    Finder finder = new Finder();
    File[] files = finder.findTxtFiles("folder");

    Map<String, List<String>> painters = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    List<String> titles = new ArrayList<>();

    for(File file : files){
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(file.getPath()), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
        String painterName = bufferedReader.readLine();
        bufferedReader.readLine();

        while(bufferedReader.readLine() != null) {
            titles.add(bufferedReader.readLine());
        }
        painters.put(painterName,titles);
    }
}

public class Finder {

    public static File[] findTxtFiles(String dirName){
        File file = new File(dirName);
        return file.listFiles((dir1, filename) -> filename.endsWith(".txt"));
    }

}
```

i have problem with list, becouse i add to map all values from list, dont know how solve this problem.

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: in this case have one list<string>, i need each different list for different key

Comment: ["I need *X*" is not a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).  Please [edit] your question to be far more specific about what help you need.

Comment: `HashMap`s are not the building stones for applications. Create a class.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need a new list for each key so create your list in the for loop.

```
public void check() throws IOException {

Finder finder = new Finder();
File[] files = finder.findTxtFiles("folder");

Map<String, List<String>> painters = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();


    for(File file : files){
        List<String> titles = new ArrayList<>();

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
        Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(file.getPath()), 
        StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
        String painterName = bufferedReader.readLine();
        bufferedReader.readLine();

        while(bufferedReader.readLine() != null) {
           titles.add(bufferedReader.readLine());
        }
        painters.put(painterName,titles);
    }
}
```